# Clear select selected value on submit

Tags: reactjs

I have a page with 3 fields:

- `SearchSelect` (`react-select`)
- `Dropdown` (`react-select`)
- `InputNumber` (`react-number-format`)

I need to clear all fields values on Submit.

The `InputNumber` is controlled so when I `setState` with the initial state the input field value is being cleared.

I'm not sure how to clear the values of the two selects, they are not controlled so how can I clear their values on submit?

The 3 fields:

```
<SearchSelect
 placeholder="Search fees"
 loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
 isAsync
 onChange={e => {
    this.makeHandleChange('fee')({
       ...fee,
       orderID: e.value.id,
    });
    this.setState({ submitted: false });
  }}
  key={searchBy}
  onFocus={() => this.getRidOfError('orderError')}
/>
<Dropdown
    options={docTypes}
    placeholder="Document Type"
    onChange={e => {
        this.makeHandleChange('fee')({
        ...fee,
        docTypeID: e.value,
      });
    }}
    onFocus={() => this.getRidOfError('docTypeError')}
/>
<InputNumber
   thousandSeparator
   prefix="$"
   value={fee.cost}
   onChange={e =>
     this.makeHandleChange('fee')({
     ...fee,
     cost: Number(
          e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, ''),
     ),
     })
   }
   onKeyUp={() => this.getRidOfError('costError')}
   error={costError}
   />
   <Button
      text="submit"
      onClick={this.handleSubmit}
      data-test="submit"
   />
```

The `handleSubmit` function:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
const { fee } = this.state;
if (this.checkValidation()) {
  addFee(fee);
  this.setState(this.initialState);
  this.setState({ submitted: true });
}
};
```

`makeHandleChange` function:

```
  makeHandleChange = changedProperty => newVal => {
    const newState = { ...this.state, [changedProperty]: newVal };
    this.setState({ ...newState });
  };
```

`Dropdown` component:

```
export default function Dropdown(props) {
  return <Select {...selectProps(props)} />;
}
```

`State`:

```
  state = {
    fee: {
      orderID: '',
      docTypeID: '',
      cost: '',
    },
    orderError: false,
    docTypeError: false,
    costError: false,
    submitted: false,
  };
```

`loadOptions`:

```
loadOptions = async partialString=> {
    const { searchBy } = state;
    const { data = [] } = await axios.get(
      `api/Orders/Search?searchString=${partialString}
    );
     return data.map(orderWithClient => {
        const { order, client } = orderWithClient;
        const clientName = client && client.firstName;
        return {
           label: order.orderNumber
           subLabel: clientName,
           value: order,
        };
     });
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you add a code for `Dropdown` for example? I see it already has `onCahnge` so maybe this won't be an issue to turn it into controlled one?

Answer (score 0):

For uncontrolled component the value will not reset until component unmount are remount again.

The best approach would be to `make your dropdown component and select controlled component too`, **which wouldn't take much change.**

**EDIT 2:**
I see your loadOptions is async function. so in your loadoptions function set options to state and then return data like below.

```js
loadOptions = async partialString => {
    const { searchBy } = state;
    const { data = [] } = await axios.get(
      `api/Orders/Search?searchString=${partialString}`
    );
    
     const loadedOptions = data.map(orderWithClient => {
        const { order, client } = orderWithClient;
        const clientName = client && client.firstName;
        return {
           label: order.orderNumber
           subLabel: clientName,
           value: order,
        };
     });
     this.setState({loadedOptions});
     return loadedOptions;
  }
);
```

Pick up selected options from loaded data on your render function like below

```js
render() {
  const fee = this.state.fee;
  const loadedOptions = this.state.loadedOptions;
  const selectedOptionForDropdown = loadedOptions.find(item => item.value === fee.docTypeID);
  const selectedOptionForSelect = loadedOptions.find(item => item.value === fee.orderID)

...
}
```

```js
<Dropdown
  options={docTypes}
  placeholder="Document Type"
  onChange={e => {
    this.makeHandleChange('fee')({
    ...fee,
    docTypeID: e.value,
    });
  }}
  value={selectedOptionForDropdown}
  onFocus={() => this.getRidOfError('docTypeError')}
/>
```

similarly for your **react-select component which also takes value as one of its props**.

```js
<SearchSelect
  placeholder="Search fees"
  loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
  isAsync
  onChange={e => {
    this.makeHandleChange('fee')({
       ...fee,
       orderID: e.value.id,
    });
    this.setState({ submitted: false });
  }}
  key={searchBy}
  value={selectedOptionForSelect}
  onFocus={() => this.getRidOfError('orderError')}
/>
```

Comment: I have tried that.. This causes the `select` to not show the selected value at all. Please note that the value is the `id` and the text is the `label`.

Comment: @user3378165 Cool. I just edited my answer by picking value from `fee.orderID`  and `fee.docId`. If you can share how object in `loadOptions` list look look like. I can provide exact value for reac t-select too.

Comment: Still same thing... Selected values are always empty

Comment: Please note, That I had mistaken, `Dropdown`  is also a `react-select` component.

Comment: ok. can you please share how items in your `loadsOptions list` look like

Comment: I can't change the code the way you suggested, this is an async select that fetches values while the user types..

Comment: ok. I did some modifications in your loaddata function. please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187650/discussion-between-gaurav-saraswat-and-user3378165).